# TwitterKit - can't display user timeline on the console

Tags: swift, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to get the user timeline using TwitterKit with fabric framework, when I run the following code I get this output rather than a timeline

> ```
> output  <TWTRUserTimelineDataSource: 0x7ff8b9447950>
> ```

```
  let client = TWTRAPIClient()
        let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)
        print(dataSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might helps you

```
    import UIKit
    import TwitterKit

    class ViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {

        convenience init() {
            let client = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
            let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)

            self.init(dataSource: dataSource)
        }

        override required init(dataSource: TWTRTimelineDataSource) {
            super.init(dataSource: dataSource)
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not displaying in a console

Comment: Its a class object show it is showing like this in console. Have you run this class?

Comment: I did and it shows this error: fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: I tried it and i get this error: fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106604/discussion-between-sourabh-sharma-and-afnan-humdan).